# Code reusing same input value every 12th input and the initial input

Tags: r, shiny

Whenever I start this app for the first time, the output value for Spare Cash (s) updates based on the previous die roll (if the last roll was a win, it increases the value, if the last value was a loss, it decreases the value), and if I restart the app it'll do it again after 12 total inputs across both runs. Restarting after that and everything is fine for some reason. Additionally, since s lags behind, the Game Over output also lags behind. Why is this?

I've tried removing e and func1 entirely to see if my issue was with the other parts of the interface, but that did not fix my problem. I wish I understood why it causes a problem in such a specific and predictable way, because I don't know what's so special about it having to rerun and having to input values 12 times. I wish I could provide more background, but I'm beyond stumped.

EDIT: I have defined betting1 as a reactive function now within the server (and changed betting1(input$amount) to betting1() accordingly) and the same issue still exists.

```
library(shiny)
e <- 0
betting1 <- function(p){
  if(is.numeric(p)==T){
    x <<- sample(1:6, size = 1)
    y <<- sample(1:6, size = 1)
    z <<- sum(x,y)
    print(z)
  if (z == 6| z == 7| z == 8| z == 12) {
    e <<- 1
    t <- p }
  else {
    e <<- 0
    t <- -p }
return(t)
}
}

func1 <- function(b){
  if (e==1){print(paste0("Won: $", b))}
  else if(e==0) {print(paste0("Lost: $", b))}}

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Game pays you back the amount that you bet. Win on a dice sum of: 6, 7, 8, or 12. Start with $100."),

fluidRow( 
  sidebarPanel("Game Info: ",br(),"Game #1",
  textOutput("numeric_amount"),
  textOutput("roll"),
  textOutput("outcome")
  ),

column(4,numericInput("amount", h3("$ Betting Amount"), value = NA)),   
column(8,submitButton("Confirm Bet"))
),
mainPanel(
  textOutput("game_info"),
  textOutput("avg"), br(),
  textOutput("plays"), br(),
  textOutput("Game_Over"), br(), br(),
  textOutput("saves")
)
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output){
v <- NULL
s <- 100
i <- 0

output$game_info <- renderText({
  l<-betting1(input$amount)
  if(input$amount>0 & is.numeric(input$amount)==T){ s<<-(s+l) }
  paste("Spare Cash: $", s)})

output$numeric_amount <- renderText({paste("Your last bet: $", input$amount)})
output$avg <- renderText({
 if(input$amount>0 & is.numeric(input$amount)==T){
   v<<-c(v, input$amount)
   paste("Average bet: $", mean(v))}     
})
output$outcome <- renderText({paste(func1(input$amount)) }) 
output$plays <- renderText({
 if(input$amount>0 & is.numeric(input$amount)==T){
   i<<-i+1
   paste("Plays: ", i)}
 else{ paste("Plays: ", i)}
})
output$roll <- renderText({
 if(input$amount>0 & is.numeric(input$amount)==T){
   paste("First Die: ", x, "  Second Die: ", y, "  Sum: ", z)}
})
output$Game_Over <- renderText({ 
 if(input$amount>0 & is.numeric(input$amount)==T){
      if (s<=0){paste("Game Over. Tally your results (Spare Cash, Avg. Bet, Plays) and send them to - with your game number.")}
   else {paste("You can choose to stop at any point. When you do, tally your results (Spare Cash, Avg. Bet, Plays) and send them to - with your game number.")         }
 }
 else { paste("Please input a number larger than 0.")}
 }) 
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as expected (no lag, even for the Game Over) if you define your function `betting1()` as a reactive function, inside your server section, instead of an outside standard function.

```
server <- function(input, output){
  v <- NULL
  s <- 100
  i <- 0

  betting1 <- reactive({
    p <- input$amount
    if(is.numeric(p)==T){
      x <<- sample(1:6, size = 1)
      y <<- sample(1:6, size = 1)
      z <<- sum(x,y)
      print(z)
      if (z == 6| z == 7| z == 8| z == 12) {
        e <<- 1
        t <- p }
      else {
        e <<- 0
        t <- -p }
      return(t)
    }
  })

[...]
```

Reactive functions are really useful in a shiny application, when a function is called several times, and that some elements of your environment are changing but not all of them. The reactive will only update what is necessary.
You can have more information [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/).

Comment: I'm sorry but it actually didn't work as I thought. As usual, when I save the app, close rstudio and open the same app back up and run it it goes back to messing up the first 12 times.